# Propagate DataMember to Sub Class

Tags: vb.net, serialization, subclass

I have two serializable classes of which the first, `Main`, includes members `Id`, and `Details`, an  enumeration of the second class, `Detail`.

Eg

```
<DataContract()>
Class [Main]
    <DataMember(Name:="id")>
    Property [Id] As Integer = 0
    <DataMember(Name:="details")>
    Property [Details] As IEnumerable(Of [Detail]) = Nothing
End Class

<DataContract()>
Class [Detail]
    <DataMember(Name:="name")>
    Property [Name] As String = Nothing
    <DataMember(Name:="dob")>
    Property [BirthDate] As Date? = Nothing
End Class
```

(This is a very simplified example so please don't ask *why* I want to do this.)

What I want to end up with is just, `Details`, the collection of `Detail`, BUT with the `Id` property from the parent, `Main`, included.

So ...

```
Id = 1, Name = "John Smith", BirthDate = #1/1/1990#
Id = 1, Name = "Jane Jones", BirthDate = #2/2/1990#
Id = 2, Name = "Jim Hicks", BirthDate = #3/3/1990#
Id = 3, Name = "Jana Walsh", BirthDate = #4/4/1990#
Id = 3, Name = "Jason Brown", BirthDate = #5/5/1990#
```

Now, I know I could simply iterate through the results and copy `Id` from the `Main` object to the `Detail` objects. But is there a way of adding `Id` to `Detail` objects via the serialization process? (Sorry if I have some nomenclature wrong here re serialization, etc.)

Note: I can't - or don't want to - make `Detail` a child class of `Main` because `Detail` is re-used in other classes.

Comment: If details has the id, then why does main need it again?

Comment: Your class structure/hierarchy lends itself better to a nested representation. Main would contain the id, then a collection of detail items that fall under it.

Comment: @OneFineDay It doesn't. Refer to the class definitions. Main has the Id, Detail doesn't. The records shown are an example of the result I want.

Comment: @Fabulous That's what I have now. But, as I said, this is a very basic example model; the actual `Main` is quite large and cumbersome and contains different incarnations of `Detail`. I strip out only the types of `Detail` that I need in the real-world application to keep things strongly types.